# Pivoting columns to rows

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a set of data where the columns I'm trying to pivot vertically are stored as such:

```
testdata <- structure(list(id = c(723L, 621L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), 
    fullName = c("Will Smith", "Chris Rock", "", "", "", "", 
    "", "", ""), latestPosts.0.locationId = c(212928653L, 34505L, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), latestPosts.0.locationName = c("Miami", 
    "Atlanta", "", "", "", "", "", "", ""), latestPosts.1.locationId = c(1040683L, 
    20326736L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), latestPosts.1.locationName = c("New York", 
    "London", "", "", "", "", "", "", ""), latestPosts.2.locationId = c(NA, 
    215307317L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), latestPosts.2.locationName = c("", 
    "Paris", "", "", "", "", "", "", ""), latestPosts.3.locationId = c(1147378L, 
    34505L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), latestPosts.3.locationName = c("Seattle", 
    "Atlanta", "", "", "", "", "", "", ""), latestPosts.4.locationId = c(1147378L, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), latestPosts.4.locationName = c("Seattle", 
    "", "", "", "", "", "", "", ""), latestPosts.5.locationId = c(238334931, 
    9432076525, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), latestPosts.5.locationName = c("San Francisco", 
    "Brooklyn", "", "", "", "", "", "", ""), latestPosts.6.locationId = c(881699386L, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), latestPosts.6.locationName = c("San Diego", 
    "", "", "", "", "", "", "", ""), latestPosts.7.locationId = c(NA, 
    234986797L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), latestPosts.8.locationId = c(1147378, 
    9021444765, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), latestPosts.8.locationName = c("Seattle", 
    "Cleveland", "", "", "", "", "", "", ""), latestPosts.9.locationId = c(NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), latestPosts.9.locationName = c(NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), latestPosts.10.locationId = c(408631288L, 
    234986797L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), latestPosts.10.locationName = c("Portland", 
    "Orlando", "", "", "", "", "", "", ""), latestPosts.11.locationId = c(52043757619, 
    34505, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), latestPosts.11.locationName = c("Nashville", 
    "Atlanta", "", "", "", "", "", "", "")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-9L))
```

I am trying to pivot where any time `latestPosts.n.locationId` OR `latestPosts.n.locationName` (in this case, `n` is a placeholder for the number in between the two) is not blank or not NA, it pivots so that the final output looks as such:

```
testdata_exp <- structure(list(id = c(723L, 724L, 725L, 726L, 727L, 728L, 729L, 
730L, 731L, 621L, 622L, 623L, 624L, 625L, 626L, 627L, 628L, 629L
), fullName = c("Will Smith", "Will Smith", "Will Smith", "Will Smith", 
"Will Smith", "Will Smith", "Will Smith", "Will Smith", "Will Smith", 
"Chris Rock", "Chris Rock", "Chris Rock", "Chris Rock", "Chris Rock", 
"Chris Rock", "Chris Rock", "Chris Rock", "Chris Rock"), locationId = c(212928653, 
1040683, 1147378, 1147378, 238334931, 881699386, 1147378, 408631288, 
52043757619, 34505, 20326736, 215307317, 34505, 9432076525, 234986797, 
9021444765, 234986797, 34505), locationName = c("Miami Beach, Florida", 
"Starbucks", "University of Evansville", "University of Evansville", 
"Downtown Evansville", "Garden Of The Gods", "University of Evansville", 
"Phi Gamma Delta - Epsilon Iota", "Nashville Pride", "University of the South", 
"Riverview Camp For Girls", "Chattanooga, Tennessee", "University of the South", 
"Grand Sirenis Riviera Maya Resort", "", "Sleepyhead Coffee", 
"Sewanee, Tennessee", "University of the South")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-18L))
```

Or for a visual representation:

[image]

A couple things to keep in mind:

1. The number of `latestPosts.n.locationId` OR `latestPosts.n.locationName` might change from dataset to dataset, so it's best to account for not knowing how many there will be. This example goes up to 11, but other times it might be more or less.
2. If there is a `locationId` present, it doesn't always mean there will be a matching `locationName` field. Using this data as an example, there is a `latestPosts.7.locationId` field but no subsequent `latestPosts.7.locationName`
   field.

Answer (score 1):

Here's another variation (also using `pivot_longer`)

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)   

 testdata %>%
    pivot_longer(-c(id, fullName),
               names_to = c("n", ".value"),
               names_pattern = "latestPosts\\.([0-9]+)\\.(.+)") %>%
  select(-n) %>%
  filter(!((is.na(locationId) | locationId == '') & (is.na(locationName) | locationName == '')))

#> # A tibble: 18 × 4
#>       id fullName    locationId locationName 
#>    <int> <chr>            <dbl> <chr>        
#>  1   723 Will Smith   212928653 Miami        
#>  2   723 Will Smith     1040683 New York     
#>  3   723 Will Smith     1147378 Seattle      
#>  4   723 Will Smith     1147378 Seattle      
#>  5   723 Will Smith   238334931 San Francisco
#>  6   723 Will Smith   881699386 San Diego    
#>  7   723 Will Smith     1147378 Seattle      
#>  8   723 Will Smith   408631288 Portland     
#>  9   723 Will Smith 52043757619 Nashville    
#> 10   621 Chris Rock       34505 Atlanta      
#> 11   621 Chris Rock    20326736 London       
#> 12   621 Chris Rock   215307317 Paris        
#> 13   621 Chris Rock       34505 Atlanta      
#> 14   621 Chris Rock  9432076525 Brooklyn     
#> 15   621 Chris Rock   234986797 <NA>         
#> 16   621 Chris Rock  9021444765 Cleveland    
#> 17   621 Chris Rock   234986797 Orlando      
#> 18   621 Chris Rock       34505 Atlanta
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do

```r
library(tidyverse)

testdata %>%
  rename_all(~sub("latestPosts\\.", "", .x)) %>%
  mutate(across(contains("location"), as.character)) %>%
  mutate(rownum = row_number()) %>%
  pivot_longer(contains("location")) %>%
  separate(name, into = c("group", "var")) %>%
  group_by(id, fullName, group, rownum) %>%
  summarise(var = c("locationId", "locationName"),
            value = if(n() == 1) c(value, NA) else value, .groups = "drop") %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = var, values_from = value) %>%
  select(id, fullName, locationId, locationName) %>%
  filter((!is.na(locationName) & nzchar(locationName)) | !is.na(locationId)) %>%
  mutate(locationId = as.numeric(locationId))
#> # A tibble: 18 x 4
#>       id fullName    locationId locationName 
#>    <int> <chr>            <dbl> <chr>        
#>  1   621 Chris Rock       34505 Atlanta      
#>  2   621 Chris Rock    20326736 London       
#>  3   621 Chris Rock   234986797 Orlando      
#>  4   621 Chris Rock       34505 Atlanta      
#>  5   621 Chris Rock   215307317 Paris        
#>  6   621 Chris Rock       34505 Atlanta      
#>  7   621 Chris Rock  9432076525 Brooklyn     
#>  8   621 Chris Rock   234986797 NA           
#>  9   621 Chris Rock  9021444765 Cleveland    
#> 10   723 Will Smith   212928653 Miami        
#> 11   723 Will Smith     1040683 New York     
#> 12   723 Will Smith   408631288 Portland     
#> 13   723 Will Smith 52043757619 Nashville    
#> 14   723 Will Smith     1147378 Seattle      
#> 15   723 Will Smith     1147378 Seattle      
#> 16   723 Will Smith   238334931 San Francisco
#> 17   723 Will Smith   881699386 San Diego    
#> 18   723 Will Smith     1147378 Seattle
```